# Clear an int[x][y] array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-management, multidimensional-array, ios-4.2

I am working on a iPhone game. Everything is working fine, but what is the correnct way to reset a array of ints in Objective-C?
The array holds the coordinates for walls in each level. The array is set, every time a new level is loaded - But how can i "clear" the array?

LevelData.h

```
int wallH[50][2];
int wallV[50][2];
```

LevelData.m

```
-(void)setLevelOne {

    // (50, 70)
    wallH[0][0] = 50;
    wallH[0][1] = 70;

    // (50, 90)
    wallH[1][0] = 50;
    wallH[1][1] = 90;

    // And so on ...
    // The same for wallV (Vertical walls in the level)
}
```

How can I "clear" the array, so it's ready for the next level?
[wallH release] doesn't work - We are talking about a c array :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can zero array using `memset` function (in your case you know the number of elements in array so you can use "hardcoded" 100 determining size):

```
memset(wallH, 0, 100*sizeof(wallH[0][0]);
```

Comment: wish I could give you another +1 for using memset, don't see enough people using that.

Comment: Ahh.. 100*sizeof(wallH[0][0]) b/c wallH is initialized as [50][2]?

Comment: Because it's only technically valid for setting raw bytes, and most folks use more complex stuff than that. ;p

Comment: @user622470 simply memset(wallH, 0, sizeof wallH) is better.